# Cached images in offline downloaded using custom downloader

Tags: android, picasso

In my application I'm using custom downloader to download images because server requires additional authorisation in request header. I'm trying to load downloaded images in offline mode, but when I'm using this custom downloader Picasso isn't loading images. Anyone could help?

```
OkHttpClient picassoClient = new OkHttpClient();

    picassoClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                                         @Override
                                         public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                             Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                                     .addHeader(RestUtils.HEADER, hash)
                                                     .build();
                                             return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                                         }
                                     }

    );

    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(mContext)
            .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(picassoClient)).build();

    picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    picasso.invalidate(RestUtils.getUrl(url));

    if (DeviceUtility.isOnline(mContext)) {
        picasso.load(RestUtils.getUrl(url))
                .networkPolicy(
                        DeviceUtility.isOnline(mContext) ?
                                NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE : NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .resize(200, 200)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(viewHolder.mImgvPicture);
    } else {
        picasso.load(RestUtils.getUrl(url))
                .networkPolicy(
                        DeviceUtility.isOnline(mContext) ?
                                NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE : NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .resize(200, 200)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(viewHolder.mImgvPicture);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You invalidate the URL right before getting it from cache:

```
picasso.invalidate(RestUtils.getUrl(url));
```

Try to invalidate only if the device is connected.